# Control shown items by set of checkboxes in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of tags that are mapped to checkboxes. In the same controller there is a list of items that have some of these tags. The items that have tags that are checked should be visible.

[Here is a plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/gN8c9CKt7dC4VCAdXyKT/preview) with the code setup. What I can't figure out is how to filter the `$scope.items` by the active (checked) tags. I tried a couple of different approaches, but being very new to angular I need a push in the right direction. I imagine the `$scope.items` should observe the `$scope.tags` and somehow filter by each tag's `active` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Creating Custom Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters).

Define a custom filter in your module:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .filter('withActiveTags', ActiveTagsFilter)
  .controller('TestController', TestController);

function ActiveTagsFilter() {
  return function (items, tags) {
    var filteredItems = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
      if (/* tags contains an active tag that's in item.tags */) {
        filteredItems.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filteredItems;
  };
}

function TestController() {
  // controller stuff
}
```

Then write something like this in your view:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | withActiveTags:tags">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Now just figure out the best way to do your filtering and you'll be all set.  Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/616icS?p=preview) example minus the filtering.  I did create a 'sample filter' to demonstrate that the filter does work.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how to pass in the actual tags I have to a custom filter function (in the html). I'd think this solution is best, considering I might reuse the same filtering mechanism in other spots as well.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is the link broken? Is there functionality that's not working?  Note that the plunker doesn't solve the original question's problem, it only demonstrates how to create a reusable custom filter.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the regular [filter directive with a custom](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) function, implemented here: http://plnkr.co/edit/dCJ3kfnIaFcpkgIuIpRT?p=preview

View change:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:tagSelected">
```

Controller change:

```
$scope.tagSelected = function(item) {
  for(var i = 0, l = $scope.tags.length; i < l; i++) {
    var t = $scope.tags[i];

    for(var j = 0, k = item.tags.length; j < k; j++) {
      if(item.tags[j] == t.name && t.active) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I toyed around with the problem some more myself also and came to this solution. Supposedly this solution is sufficient if I will never reuse this type of filter anywhere else again.

Answer (score 1):

or bit different solution http://plnkr.co/edit/GSm64d8pmYorcU3wrXCt?p=preview

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in items |  selectedTags : tags ">
```

js:

```
.filter('selectedTags', function() {
  return function(items, tags) {

    var filtered = [];

    tags.forEach(function(tag) {

      if (tag.active === true) {


        items.forEach(function(item) {
          {

            if (item.tags.indexOf(tag.name) > -1) {


              if (filtered.indexOf(item) == -1) {
                filtered.push(item);
              }

            }
          }
        })
      }

    });

    return filtered;

  };
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the plunkr. This seems to be similar to @nwayne 's answer, and equally applicable.